# How to make my ios app reactive to wifi change events

Tags: ios, swift, broadcastreceiver

Can an ios app (possibly not active) be notified if there is a change in wifi network connected to(getting disconnected from, or getting connected to new ntwk)?

I am to build an app that (even in inactive state) should get notified when connected to a particular wifi network and do some stuff.

In android i was able to achieve it using BroadcastReceiver is there any such facility in ios?

Thanks,
Praneeth.

Comment: did it worked for you?

Comment: Hi Rajan,

My app has two parts,
Part 1 - To make it reactive to wifi changes,
Part 2 - To program some other stuff .

As I figured out That the Part 2 is impossible, I abandoned this idea of my app and have'nt really tried this out.

Thank you very much For the Help

Answer (score 2):

We have a class called `Reachability` in iOS for detecting any network flicker/disconnection/connection.
Reachability class can be found [here](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift/tree/master/Reachability)

Usage

Add **Reachability.swift** class in your project.

> **This is a Swift 2.x version code and not 3.0**

For **Swift 3.x** version check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40068225/2545465)

Sample of **Swift 3.x** 
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bph33b12tyc7fpd/AAD2pGbgW3UnqgQoe7MGPpKPa?dl=0

In your `AppDelegate` make an object of `Reachability` class

```
private var reachability:Reachability!
```

In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` add a observer for your network reachability

```
//Network Reachability Notification check 

//add an observer to detect whenever network changes.
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(checkForReachability), name: ReachabilityChangedNotification, object: nil)

do {self.reachability = try Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
} catch {
}

do {
try self.reachability.startNotifier()
} catch{
}
```

And make your selector function `checkForReachability` to detect network changes/network disconnects in `AppDelegate`

```
func checkForReachability(notification:NSNotification) {
    let reachability = notification.object as! Reachability
    if reachability.isReachable() {
        if reachability.isReachableViaWiFi() {
            print("Reachable via WiFi")
        } else {
            print("Reachable via Cellular")
        }
    } else {
        print("Network not reachable")
    }
}
```

Whenever there is a network change/network break or whenever network will flicker, the `Reachability` class will fire a `ReachabilityChangedNotification` which will ultimately call this user defined method `checkForReachability`. So, you can handle anything here.

Comment: it get called only 2 times .... later it is not calling swift 5.1

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the above answer you can use the following for **Swift 3**

```
let reachability = Reachability()!

reachability.whenReachable = { reachability in
    // this is called on a background thread, but UI updates must
    // be on the main thread, like this:
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        if reachability.isReachableViaWiFi() {
            print("Reachable via WiFi")
        } else {
            print("Reachable via Cellular")
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps..

Cheers!!