# My Reachability Notifier is only able to be called once

Tags: ios, swift, reachability

So, I have the following in my AppDelegate.
It will notify my when I turn my WIFI off but will not react after that initial run.
I have had this working in the past.
I'm on swift 3 with Xcode 8 and the reachability that is for this version of the swift and xCode.

I'm hoping to get a solution to this.
Thanks.

```
    var reachability: Reachability?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        self.reachability = Reachability()

         NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.reachabilityChanged(_:)), name: ReachabilityChangedNotification, object: reachability)

        do {
            try self.reachability?.startNotifier()
        } catch {
            print("Unable to start Notifier")
        }

        return true
    }

    func reachabilityChanged(_ note:Notification){
        print("is in here")
        let reachability = note.object as! Reachability
        if reachability.isReachable{
            print("is Reachable")
            // self.amConnected.text = "YES"
            //self.amConnected.fadeOut(duration: 2.0)
        }else{
            print("IsNotReachable")
            //self.amConnected.text = "No"
            //self.amConnected.fadeIn(duration: 2.0)
        }
        print("Changed status")    
    }
```

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 4):

There are some changes in Reachability in Swift 3. Download the latest `Reachability.swift` file and add that in your project. [Link](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift/blob/master/Reachability/Reachability.swift)

For **Swift 2.x** code please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984687/2545465)

> **Swift 3.x code**

Now in your `AppDelegate` take a `Reachability` class object

```
private var reachability:Reachability!

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    //Network Reachability Notification check
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reachabilityChanged), name: ReachabilityChangedNotification, object: nil)

    self.reachability = Reachability.init()
    do {
        try self.reachability.startNotifier()
    } catch {
    }
    return true
}
```

`reachabilityChanged` method defination

```
//MARK:- Network Check
func reachabilityChanged(notification:Notification) {
    let reachability = notification.object as! Reachability
    if reachability.isReachable {
        if reachability.isReachableViaWiFi {
            print("Reachable via WiFi")
        } else {
            print("Reachable via Cellular")
        }
    } else {
         print("Network not reachable")
    }
}
```

This will be always called whenever user switches from Wifi to Cellular and vice versa or when Network Connects and Disconnects and vice versa.
 Working fine in my case.

Read the [documentation](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift#swift-3-breaking-changes) for more details in **Swift 3 breaking changes** section

Made a sample for you

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bph33b12tyc7fpd/AAD2pGbgW3UnqgQoe7MGPpKPa?dl=0

Comment: Made your updates...and had the same result...fires on load that there is an internet connection...when I disable the wifi it notfies me...then when I turn it back on there is no notification.....

Comment: Man, are you keeping your app in background? Well its working in my case, enabling-disabling WIFI , disabling internet cellular

Comment: I will just give a link to the sample and then let me know

Comment: See the edit and download the project from the link, run it and do altering with internet and let me know. Keep your app in foreground

Comment: If you kept in background and then disable wifi, whenever you again enter the app, it will come in `reachabilityChanged` selector method

Comment: It is in the simulator so always in the foreground. It fires "Reachable via WiFi" when the app lauchnes. then when I turn off the wifi I get "Network not reachable" and then when I turn back on the wifi I get nothing ....then I turn it off I get nothing...seems like it only works those first two times. I copied your code directly into my AppDelegate.

Comment: Dude, check on device. I checked on device and it works perfect

Comment: ok I will have to set up a label or something to receive the changes It might take awhile to set that up.

Comment: Actually I checkout on simulator too and it works the same as device. It is calling whenver wifi connects and disconnects

Comment: Hi there...actually after a reboot of the simulator is it now working even with the original code...was a weird simulator issue

Comment: So I'm back to square 1 again. This is driving me NUTS...it apparently wasn't the simulator...

Comment: What's the problem you are facing?

Comment: I think you should test this on device too. I believe this issue is with iOS 10 simulator only

Comment: Probably but I only have an iOS 9 compatible device currently.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `nil` for the `object` parameter in `addObserver`. Also, for Swift 3, I had to initialize it with `self.reachability = Reachability.forInternetConnection()`

Comment: there is no longer a forInternetConnection method.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 8 and downloaded the example yesterday from [Apple's sample Reachability code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html). Xcode actually prompted me to use `forInternetConnection` and it works fine in Swift 3. It's really just calling through to the System Configuration Framework anyway.