# Wifi-Network Changed Notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, xcode8

I am using [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) demo for getting network stat change notification and by using this code ,I am able to get callback when wifi is on/off, But if I am changing wifi connection from one network to another then I am not able to get callback of network change.
     As I have search the code and found this may be possible by using following callback but I don't know how to use this in my code

```
typedef void (*SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack)   (
                    SCNetworkReachabilityRef            target,
                    SCNetworkReachabilityFlags          flags,
                    void                 *  __nullable  info
                    );
```

can any one please help me to get network change callback with sample code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using this [Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) files then its easy.
Add an Observer inside the viewWillAppear

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityDidChange:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
```

And implement the observer method

```
- (void)reachabilityDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    Reachability *reachability = (Reachability *)[notification object];

    if ([reachability isReachable] && [reachability isReachableViaWiFi]) {
        NSLog(@"Reachable via Wifi");
    } 
}
```

**Updated**

Add the following code inside the Network change completion block of your Reachability handler. By Sending the `SCNetworkReachabilityFlag` as a parameter to the method.

```
-(BOOL)isReachableViaWiFi :(SCNetworkReachabilityFlags)flags {

        // Check we're reachable
        if((flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable))
        {
            // Check we're NOT on WWAN
            if((flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN))
            {
                return NO;
            }
            return YES;
        }
     return NO;
}
```

Comment: can you please help me so that I can able to get callback from "SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack" ?

Comment: "viewWillAppear" will not call when app is lunch after pressing home button.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984687/7456236) post may help you. 
As he said, Whenever there is a network change/network break or whenever network will flicker, the Reachability class will fire a `ReachabilityChangedNotification` which will ultimately call this user defined method `checkForReachability`. So, you can handle anything here.

Comment: I am using objective-C code.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

- (void) reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{
 Reachability* curReach = [note object];
 NSParameterAssert([curReach isKindOfClass:[Reachability class]]);
 [self updateInterfaceWithReachability:curReach];
}


"reachabilityChanged" is not calling when wifi is changed by user

Comment: can you please help me so that I can able to get callback from "SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack

Answer (score 0):

Add observer :- 
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

```
-(void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice
{
    // called after network status changes
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    if(internetStatus == NotReachable)
    {

    }
    else if([internetReachable connectionRequired])
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please help me so that I can able to get callback from "SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack